# Is a shopping cart a model or viewmodel?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am trying to implement a shopping cart system in my app which is proving to be more confusing/difficult than I expected.

Currently my implementation looks like this:

```
public class CartItem
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get { return Quantity * Product.Price; } }
}

public class Cart
{
    public ObservableCollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddItemCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand RemoveItemCommand { get; set; }
    public void AddItem(Product product)
    {
    }
    public void RemoveItem(Product product)
    {
    }
}
```

Specifically, I am having a hard time trying to find out where it belongs within the MVVM pattern. This implementation works until the `Quantity` variable on a `CartItem` is modified by something other than the `Cart` (such as the view) it belongs to.

Some questions I have asked myself:

- Is a shopping cart an abstraction of an object? Yes => It's a model.
- Will it be serialized/deserialized to and from a database? Yep, so it's still a model.
- Does it serve data to a view? Yes. It's a view model.
- Does it act on or modify that data? Yes, so it's a viewmodel.

Comment: The **CartItem** is definitely a Model. The **Cart** is more of a Controller that the View would bind to so put that in the ViewModel

Comment: So is your actual question "How to update `Cart.ItemCount` and `Cart.Total` on the **view**, when the `CartItem.Quantity` changes on one of the `CartItem`s stored in the `Cart.CartItems`-collection?" or "What part of the MVVM pattern these classes currently represent: Model, ViewModel or View?"

Comment: Yes.  I mean, no.  Definitely yo.  Possibly nes.  Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm going to say is the way I see MVVM, so maybe it's not totally accurate but I've seen others think the same.

**In my opinion, both Cart and CartItem are Model.**

When I build MVVM App I have:

1. **View**: Only Xaml with no code Behind
2. **ViewModel**: which contains one or several model object and some other properties
3. **Model**: Which appears to be a DTO Model and every properties implements INotifyPropertyChanged (Or RaisePropertieChanged if you use MVVM-Light Plugin).

   The model can have some "Helper properties". For exemple, your "Subtotal" propertie.
4. **DomainModel**: Which is your data from your database. Basically your DomainModel has the same structure of your table (more or less)

Obviously there is also a Service Layer but this is not the point.

To map the model to the DomainModel I use Automapper. It's quite simple.

You could merge the Model And DomainModel layer but personnaly I don't like this.
And anyway I use a PocoGenerator library so the MVVM code would be erased everytime I update the structure of my database.

One last thing, I've found using MVVM-Light was very helpfull. But, again, it's just my opinion.

EDIT:

I forgot:
I think that the ICommand and the method should not be there. All the ICommand must be placed in the ViewModel Class.